# useSpring Hook returns 'You atttempted to set lastVelocity' with the value 0 error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently getting started with [useSpring](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-spring) in react native . I have the following very simple component

```
import React  from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring'

const Pane = () => {

    const props = useSpring(() => ({opacity: 1}))


    return (
        <View style={{ props }}>
            <Text> 'test' </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Pane;
```

However, rendering this in my simulator for React Native I get the following: What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap the content of the style prop in an extra object, which is not needed, just pass the props as prop.

Also, i believe you have to set the props to an animated view instead of the regular RN view.

```
import React  from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring'

const AnimatedView = animated(View)

const Pane = () => {

const props = useSpring(() => ({opacity: 1}))

return (
    <AnimatedView style={props}>
        <Text> 'test' </Text>
    </AnimatedView>
 )
}

export default Pane;
```

Comment: unfortunately that made zero difference.

Comment: @Squiggs. see updated answer, you don't have to wrap the props in an extra object

Answer (score 0):

If your `React` version is `16.7` or higher, you can use `hooks`.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0);

    return (
        <View style={{ opacity }}>
            <Button
                onPress={() => setOpacity(opacity + 1)}
                title="Click me"
                color="red"
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: useSpring is a hook. an animation library hook which I'm specifically trying to get working.

Comment: @Squiggs My words can have the same effect without using them.

Comment: right. But the flexibility of this particular library is what I really wanted to sort out - this was an example in simplicity before expansion into other more complex concepts.